# Solaris ps aux command specific output. Why do need the `ww` flags to find matches with grep?

Tags: grep, solaris, ps

I'm starting to use Oracle Solaris 11.2 SPARC.

In Linux, I can write

```
ps aux | grep *some_data*
```

... but that doesn't show any result on Solaris.

Instead I need to say

```
ps auxww | grep *some_data*
```

I had a look at `man ps` to find more information about `ww`

> If the option letter is repeated, that is, -ww,
>            this option uses arbitrarily wide output

Why do I need to use `ww` to get anything to `grep`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux the `ps` command detects whether the output is to a terminal or not.  If it is to a terminal then it truncates the output to the terminal width.  If it is not on a terminal then it doesn't truncate.  Effectively it behaves as if it automatically adds the `ww` flags.

You can see the difference by typing `ps aux` and `ps aux | cat`

In your example you are piping the output to `grep` and so it acts as if you typed `ps auxww | grep`.

For portability you should always use the `ww` flags if you want to see all the data beyond (say) 80 characters.

Note: you're using the BSD form of the `ps` command, so on Solaris make sure you're calling the right one!

Comment: Solaris 11 `ps` actually accepts both the System V and the BSD syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You are using non standard BSD options, whether under Linux or Solaris.

The portable way is to use the `-o` option to specify which fields you want to appear, here for example `ps -o pid,args`. Note that unless you are using a recent 11.3 update or newer, the argument list will be limited to 80 characters unless you are root or own the process.

Alternatively, you might use `pgrep -f` which will search for the full command line.